# Error al acceder a base de datos SQLAlchemy y mysql

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysqlconnector

Tengo instalado un Ubuntu server !6.04.4 LTS, mysql 5.7.21 y python 3.5.2.
Estoy desarrollando un script en python que me de la información de las bases de datos existentes. 
El problema, es que al ejecutar el script siempre me da este error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/rafa/Bash-toolkit/infobd.py", line 22, in 
>       engine = create_engine('mysql://'+usuariobd+':'+contra+'@'+host+':'+puerto)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py", line 424, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 81, in create
>       dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 102, in dbapi
>       return **import**('MySQLdb')
>   ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Mi código es este:

```
#!/bin/python3
from sqlalchemy import *
#Antes de abrir la conexión, se necesitarán los datos del usuario
#Borramos los espacios con la f(x) strip() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/how-do-i-trim-whitespace-from-a-python-string
print("Introduzca el nombre del usuario")
usuariobd = input().strip()
print("Introduzca su contraseña")
contra = input()
print("Introduzca el host")
host = input().strip()
print("Introduzca el puerto a conectar (3306)")
puerto = str(input())
#Forzamos que el número que llega es un entero https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number
print("Se va a realizar la conexión con el usuario "+ usuariobd + "@" + host+ " con el puerto "+puerto)

#comprobamos que no llegan valores vacíos
if len(usuariobd) == 0 or len(contra)==0 or len(host) == 0 or len(puerto) == 0:
    print("Debes introducir todos los datos")
    exit()
#Probamos la conexión
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689895/list-of-databases-in-sqlalchemy
engine = create_engine('mysql://'+usuariobd+':'+contra+'@'+host+':'+puerto)
#Obtenemos info de las BDS disponibles
consulta = engine.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
listatablas = consulta.fetchall()
print(listatablas)
```

Comment: el error indica que te falta la libreria `MySQLdb`, instalalo con `sudo apt-get install  python3-mysqldb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te indica que falta el módulo ***MySQLdb***, debido a no existir este es cuando ***sqlalchemy*** da error al intentar importarlo.
En ubuntu lo encuentras en los mismos repositorios y puedes instalarlo:

### Para python 2

sudo apt install python-mysqldb

### Para python 3

sudo apt install python3-mysqldb

Hay otras alternativas, algunas de ellas se pueden observar desde el gestor de paquetes **pip** o **pip3**:
pip search mysql
pip3 search mysql

Aunque en el caso de Ubuntu/Debian probablemente te funcione correctamente desde los repositorios (Mi opción preferida)

Comment: Sí, me funcionó desde los repositorios

Answer (score 2):

Actualmente `mysql` no esta soportado por `python 3`. Sin embargo existen alternativas como: [mysqlclient-python](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) y [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)

Para instalar usas pip:

```
pip install mysql-python (python 2)
pip install mysqlclient (python 3)
apt-get install python-mysqldb (Ubuntu, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

No tienes instalado un driver para que se conecte e interactué con la base de datos MySQL, tienes varias opciones como se muestra en la [documentación ofical](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql). Entre ellos tienes:

- **[mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient)**:

  - Fork del MySQLdb1 pero con soporte para Python 3.
  - Escrito en C y la opción con mejor rendimiento.
  - Instala con `$ pip3 install mysqlclient` o con el paquete `python3-mysqldb` que proporciona el SO.
  - Cadena de conexión:

    ```
    mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>
    ```
- **[PyMySQL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL)**:

  - Cliente Python puro.
  - Instalar con `$ pip3 install PyMySQL`.
  - Cadena de conexión:

    ```
    mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>[?<options>]
    ```
- **[mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/8.0.6)**:

  - Cliente en Python puro.
  - [Soporte oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) por parte de Oracle.
  - Instala con `$ pip3 install mysql-connector-python`
  - Cadena de conexión:

    ```
    mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>
    ```

A la hora de crear tu engine como puedes observar se sigue la sintaxis:

```
dialecto+driver://usuario:contraseña@host:puerto/base_de_datos
```

Que te permite indicar que driver ha de usarse.