# ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Tags: mysql, python

He instalado pip. Y ahora intento instalar *MySQL* y me devuelve esto. ¿Como podría arreglar esto?. No se como hacerlo.

`(myproject) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-1kpfuxw_/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-1kpfuxw_/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`
    
    `----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1kpfuxw_/MySQL-python/`

Comment: Probablemente estás intentando instalar `MySQL-python` en **Python 3**, cuando solo es compatible para Python 2 (el paquete `ConfigParser`  de la stdlib fue renombrado a `configparser` en Py3, por eso el error). Además, no ha sido actualizado desde 2014... Te aconsejo usar otro cliente que funcione en Python 3 y que esté mantenido, puedes mirarte  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/154102/15089 donde dejo algunas de las alternativas más conocidas. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.